# Tensorflow sess.run issue

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)

with open(r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\New folder (8)\Docify-master\api\data\ctpn.pb', 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    # print("sdsds",graph_def)
    # text_format.Merge(f.read(), graph_def) 
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    # print("sss",graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read()))
    sess.graph.as_default()
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    # print("hhdsd",tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
input_img = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('Placeholder:0')
output_cls_prob = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('Reshape_2:0')
output_box_pred = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('rpn_bbox_pred/Reshape_1:0')

textdetector = TextDetector()
```

sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
TypeError: Argument `fetch` = None has invalid type "NoneType". Cannot be None

i need know how to fix it